Mongo DB next JS, api is inserting more than once
When a project is going to be inserted into the trending collection for the first time.
is going to be inserted more than once which is not what I want.
this is the backend:

import clientPromise from '@/lib/mongoDB';
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        res.status(405).json({ error: true, message: 'Wrong method' });
        return;
    }

    try {
        const client = await clientPromise;
        const db = client.db('ton3-space');

        const trendingCollection = db.collection('trending-gems');
        const gemCollection = db.collection('gems');

        const { address, gemURL } = req.body;

        if (!address || !gemURL) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: true, message: 'Missing arguments' });
            return;
        }

        const gem = await gemCollection.findOne({ url: gemURL });
        if (!gem) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: true, message: 'Gem does not exist' });
            return;
        }

        const gemID = new ObjectId(gem._id);
        const now = new Date();
        const trendExpire = new Date(now.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 24 hours from now

        // Find the gem in the trending collection
        let isGemTrending = await trendingCollection.findOne({ gem: gemID });

        if (!isGemTrending) {
            // Gem is not trending yet, so we add it to the trending collection only once
            const trendingSchema = {
                gem: gemID,
                trends_by: [address],
                trends: 1,
                trend_expire: trendExpire,
            };

            await trendingCollection.insertOne(trendingSchema);
            res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Gem is now trending' });
            return; // Ensure the function exits after inserting
        }

        // Gem is already trending
        const { trends_by, trend_expire } = isGemTrending;

        // Check if the current trend has expired
        if (now > trend_expire) {
            // Reset trends and trends_by
            await trendingCollection.updateOne(
                { gem: gemID },
                {
                    $set: {
                        trends_by: [address],
                        trends: 1,
                        trend_expire: trendExpire,
                    },
                }
            );
            res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Gem trend has been reset and now trending' });
        } else {
            // Check if the address has already trended this gem in the last 24 hours
            if (trends_by.includes(address)) {
                res.status(400).json({ error: true, message: 'Address has already trended this gem within the last 24 hours' });
                return;
            } else {
                // Update the trending data
                await trendingCollection.updateOne(
                    { gem: gemID },
                    {
                        $push: { trends_by: address },
                        $inc: { trends: 1 },
                    }
                );
                res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Gem trend updated' });
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating trending gem: ', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: true, message: 'Internal server error' });
    }
}



Like you can see if !isGemTrending I insert it into the db and make a return so it should end there but the same IF statement runs more than once. But I maybe think the issue is how i call it this is how I call it:

    const mutation = useMutation({
        mutationFn: async ({ address, gemURL }) => {
            const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}api/gems/post/update-trending`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ address, gemURL }),
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                const errorData = await response.json();
                throw new Error(errorData.message);
            }

            const data = await response.json();
            return data;
        },
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            console.log(data.message); // Log the success message
            setHasTrended(true);
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.error('Failed to update trending:', error.message); // Log the error message
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (id && wallet && address && !hasTrended) {
            mutation.mutate({ address, gemURL: gem.url });
        }
    }, [id, wallet, address, hasTrended, gem.url, mutation]);



I tried to set a hasTrended state to track when it has runned but that do not helps

Are you running this using the react dev server with strict mode on? If so, that will cause your components to render twice, so useEffect() will trigger on each render.

@EricFrancis12 i dont think so it used to work .
But i just updated the API to delete dublications that works but not optimal

Did you try adding a console.log() inside the useEffect() to see how many times it's running?

@EricFrancis12 the useEffect() runs 3 times + the mutations runs 2 times in the console

The API is not inserting twice, you are calling the API twice because your useEffect hook runs multiple times, try checking the values that you passed to useEffect they are changing after the condition inside your hook is true. if you include your full frontend component maybe I can help better.
